# Accesing the Sharepoint Online Document Getting Error The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure

I am accessing the document from the SharePoint Doc Library from the Azure Web API Hosted on the Azure. List item i can access properly. but, when I am trying to read the document Getting the error message The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Below is the code which i have written.

```
        var userToken = this.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
        var newToken = await GetSharePointAccessToken(doc.sharePointUrl, userToken);
        using (var context = new ClientContext(doc.sharePointUrl))
        {
            context.ExecutingWebRequest +=
                (s, e) => e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add(
                "Authorization", "Bearer " + newToken);
         var web = context.Web;
         var oList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employee");

         ListItem item = oList.GetItemById(doc.docID);
         context.Load(item);
         context.Load(item, i => i.File);
         context.ExecuteQuery();
         FileInformation fInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, item["FileRef"].ToString());
         var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef);

         }
```

At this line I am getting the exception

```
     FileInformation fInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, item["FileRef"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [OpenBinaryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarystream(v=office.15).aspx)

```
context.Load(item, i => i.File);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var filedata = item.File.OpenBinaryStream();
context.ExecuteQuery();
System.IO.Stream filestream = filedata.Value;
```